# Is boolean size 1 bit when we serialize it and save in disk?

Tags: serialization, boolean, size, byte, bit

I heard a boolean 1 byte in ram because otherwise cpu cannot address it. I am wondering is a boolean 1 bit when we serialize it on C# ?

Comment: No.  Wouldn't be worth it considering you'll have 7 bits left that you can't use for anything else except for other bools.  And having 8 bool fields in a class would be coding style that nobody will encourage :)

Comment: Main idea is storing strings. my strings just contains english characters and 0 to 9. I thought to use a dictionary like "a" = 0, ..... , "9" = 30. In this case 2^5 = 5-bit. Look all chars in string and find representation then convert 2-base then store as bit ? I think idea is well :D. I have 250.000 Object * 4 String * each 15 char * 3 bit(gain) = 5mb gain @HansPassant

Comment: Some embedded controllers actually have bit-addressable data, but assuming you are on a typical PC, there is no advantage today to trying to save this kind of space.  Memory is generally plentiful, and so is disk space.  If you have a huge data set to write to disk, and are running out of space, consider writing your own serializer that packs 8, 5-bit quantities into 5 bytes.  Or use a compression library.  But again, only if you have a proven space issue, as this complicates your code.

Comment: Saw your update.  5 MB is still small today, I wouldn't worry about size in that range.

Comment: I have enough space. Im intern. They told me that i should compress if my method works i will gain 278mb. Like 13.000.000 objects and it will increase :D @roderickyoung

Comment: You are talking about Huffman coding.  Re-inventing GZipStream is not a good idea.

Comment: I tryed but its is not suitible my case. I think GZipStream is suitable for long strings not like length 15 @HansPassant

Comment: What is 5 mb supposed to mean then?  Millibytes?

Comment: Intern or not, and engineer's duty is to push back if the customer (your boss) is asking for something that will not benefit them.  Advise that you could compress, but it will be at a cost of performance, and maintainability in your code.  And also that a 278 MB gain is still small on today's computers.  But if the boss insists, the customer is always right.  Buffer 1 MB of data internally, use zlib or some other standard compression library to compress that, then write out to disk or your device.  You will likely get better compression than you would by simply packing bits.

Answer (score 0):

No, 
Nothing in a computer is ever truly 1 'bit'. A byte is the smallest meaningful piece of information in a computer. 
It may only be 1 bit of information but it takes an entire byte to store it.

Comment: I am trying to store some data. In my case byte-8bit is so big to use. I want to convert my data to some 5-bit format. If i do like this will i gain any free space ? @Paul Swetz

Comment: Thank you. now i understand :)